# Reading and appending a file in C

Tags: c

I am new to C and I wrote a code that collects student data, but I am facing few problems.It's not reading the file, secondly, when I try to append, new data is not being added to a new line. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int giveChoiceForFileOpenType();
void WriteFile();
void ReadFile();
void ApendFile();
void printChoices();
int openFileFromConsole(FILE *fp1);
void saveStudentGradeInfoTofile(FILE *fp1);

typedef struct student {
    char name[50];
    char id [20];
    int score;
}student;


int main() {


    printChoices();
    int choice = giveChoiceForFileOpenType();

    switch(choice){
    case 1: WriteFile();
        break;
    case 2: ReadFile();
        break;
    case 3: ApendFile();
        break;
    default: printf("Error!!!\n");
    }


    return 0;
}


void WriteFile(){
    FILE *fp1 =fopen("E://registry.csv", "w");
    openFileFromConsole(fp1);
    saveStudentGradeInfoTofile(fp1);
    fclose(fp1);

}
void ReadFile(){
    FILE *fp2 = fopen("E://registry.csv", "r");
    openFileFromConsole(fp2);

    fclose(fp2);
}

void ApendFile(){

    FILE *fp3 = fopen("E://registry.csv", "a");
    openFileFromConsole(fp3);
    saveStudentGradeInfoTofile(fp3);
    fclose(fp3);

}
void printChoices(){

    printf("1.Write\n");
    printf("2.Read\n");
    printf("3.Append\n");
    return;
}

int giveChoiceForFileOpenType(){

    int choice;
    printf("Select fileopen type:");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    return choice;

}

int openFileFromConsole(FILE *fp1){

    if(fp1 == NULL  )
    {
        printf("Error!");
        return 0;
    }
    return 1 ;
}
void readingDataFromFile(){



}

void saveStudentGradeInfoTofile(FILE *fp1)
{

    int numOfStudent ;
    student s[100];
    printf ("Get the number of students :");
    scanf("%d",&numOfStudent);

    for(int i = 0; i < numOfStudent; i++) {


        printf("\nEnter ID number:");

        scanf(" %s",s[i].id);

        printf("Enter name: ");
        scanf("%s,",s[i].name);

        printf("Enter score: ");
        scanf("%d",&s[i].score);

        fprintf(fp1,"%s, %s, %d",s[i].id,s[i].name,s[i].score);

        printf("\n");

    }
}
```

Comment: "It's not reading the file"??? You never tell the computer to print the contents of the file, why would you expect it to do so, then?

Comment: @ForceBru Perhaps OP is using a debugger or another tool to read the file?  IAC, code thats does print would be nice for reviewers.  I suspect this code is stub code (not of OP's authorship) meant for OP to fill in.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to put your output onto separate lines, you need to add in the `\n` character in your format string like this

```
fprintf(fp1,"%s, %s, %d\n",s[i].id,s[i].name,s[i].score);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure someone will correct me if I am incorrect here, but it doesn't look like you are doing anything with the file once you have used `fopen`.

When you call `ReadFile()` it uses `fopen` with a filename and in read mode, which is fine. Then it calls `openFileFromConsole(fp2)`, however all that function does is `return 1` to the caller function and then closes the file.

If I've missed something I'm sure someone will correct.

Comment: Absolutely correct. `fopen` is no magic function: it merely opens a file and doesn't read or write anything to it.

Comment: @ForceBru this is what I thought. I would imagine the OP would have to incorporate a loop with an `fgetc` or `fgets` if they wanted to actually read this file.